# How can I get a slot machine effect in the IOS SDK with text?

Tags: ios, text, scroll, swipe-gesture

I need to create a list of words then have the words cycle through in a slot machine effect when swiped from top to bottom.

the only issues I'm having problems figuring out is the scrolling text part. UIPICKERVIEW doesn't cycle around (plus I need to only show one option at a time). I've hunted for examples and/or tutorials regarding this but haven't found anything that points me in the right direct.

Anyone know of a tutorial or have suggestions where I can get started or further my research? thanks.

Comment: So, could you find solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

You could use iCarousel for this:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Run the Basic iOS Demo and select the Cylinder carousel type in vertical orientation with wrap on. If that looks like what you want, the documentation will explain how you can set it up in your project.